# User Permissions for login page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am doing a project for school, and I am new to php and mysql.

I have to create one loginpage with 3 different users like `corres`, `principal` and the `staff`

In the table field what type I have to give like `ENUM` or `SET`?
I want to assign 0 for `corres`,1 for `principal` and 3 for `staff`.

How to do this, and should I give any field in the login page in php?

But I am going to create only 2 tables one for `corres` and other one is for `staff`

correc table fields are

`corrs_id,username,password,staff_id,staff_role`

staff table fields are 
`staff_id,staff_role,name,qualification,address,state` etc.

Both the tables have 2 common fields `staff_id` and `staff_role`.
Now how to connect 2 tables, and when **username** and **password** is given it should first check the `staff_role` like `principal` or a `staff` using `staff_id` from the `corres` table according to tht the page should open.

Please help me in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the fields in the same table and add another field like staff_role (Tree structure).
and based on the value returned from this field redirect to the particular page.

Say table has these data
**employee_id emp_name password emp_role**
and data like
**3  Jack   password    staff**
Algorithm

```
$emp_role= $record['emp_role'];

  if($emp_role == "principle")
 Header("location: principle.php");
else if($emp_role == "staff")
Header("location: staff.php");
else if($emp_role == "corres")
Header("location: corres.php");
else
Header("location:StaffRoleNotDefined.php");
```

Comment: Did you add the column to table which stores the role of an employee, then retrieve that column for the logged in staff, check if the roles match and redirect accordingly.

Comment: can u just see this link.......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955870/joining-tables-in-mysql-with-one-common-field-but-different-values-for-the-commo/8956303#8956303

Comment: i mentioned the ful code..register.php and login.php..i can register but in the register table the emp_role field is not filled with the option i selected throu radio button and when i login with username and password in the login page the page is not connected to the corresponding page

Comment: So the error is in register page, check value of the radio box posted. if its null fixing it will solve your problem. have you added the name attribute of the radio button.

Comment: the emp_role value is posted in the db..how to rectify that???...using emp_role in registertable how to give username and password in the loginpage code??

Comment: On registering a employee is emp_role value being filled in database, then when user enter's username and password query the database to check if they are correct and the emp_role, and redirect accordingly

Answer (score 0):

My idea is make a common table for all user types like corres,principal and the staff and store
all info like username, password etc with staff type in it which you are taking in enum filed.

I don't know why you want to do with 2 tables.

It can be doable in single table with enum field for user type  corres,principal and the staff

Comment: Steps.. ?  Have to just insert values in database from your form.

Comment: i just created logindetails table:admin_id,username,password,staff_id,staff_role,signup date,user_permissions and staffdetaiks table:staff_role,staff_id,name,address,age,gender,city,state,phone no

Comment: i just created logindetails table:admin_id,username,password,staff_id,staff_role,signup date,user_permissions and staffdetaiks table:staff_role,staff_id,name,address,age,gender,city,state,phone n0..and i gave username and pwd for the corr and princ...now my question is if i gave usernme and password in the loginpage first it shud find whether the users is aa corr or princ or staff using staff_id from logindetails table and then connect to the staff table to find the role like corr or prin or staff..wht will be the code in php

Comment: any code like this in php loginpage file??checkLogin($privilege){

//Use Cookie to determine which user is accessing page
//Determine if user is active (toggled when logged in)
//retrieve users privilege level
//check against passed in value 
//return true or false
}

//Php for website.

if(checkLogin(0)){

//0 – guest
//1 – user
//3 – admin
}