# Joining tables in MySql with one common field but different values for the common field

Tags: php, mysql

how to join 3 tables with one common field like

- table1:c_id,username,password,c_role
- table2:p_id,username,password,c_role
- table3:s_id,username,password,c_role

in this **c_role** field is common 
here i assigned

- enum '1' for c_role in table1
- enum '2' for c_role in table2
- enum '3' for c_role in table3

for giving rights to 3 different users like corres, principal and for a staff when they login..
Now when they login it should identify the user and take them to their page..

Comment: First off, why would you have three different tables with the same data? Username and pass should be saved only once

Comment: for 3 users i created 3 different tables.....or else any other option for that u hve

Comment: Why would you have three different tables for three users? You can choose their privileges in one table only, no need for three.

Comment: i dont know much about mysql just say me how to do this

Comment: how to create tables,query etc...code to insert in php etc etc..

Comment: in other words you expect a 'how to design relational databases, administer MySQL server and program in PHP` tutorial in a single answer on StackOverflow. Good luck with that. I might award a bounty to a person who achieves that.

Comment: and for the staff table i have extra fields like name,address,phone no,state,country,city,dob..bcoz corres have rights to enter the details about the staff..

Comment: You are asking more then any of us are ready to help you. We can help with a specific problem, but when you don't know anything.. we have lives too you know

Answer (score 1):

The only joins would be on username (and password ?) unless c_id, p_id and s_id are all the same id?

You can't join on role seeing as they are different in each table, aside from an utterly daft role = 1 in Table1 is the equivalent of role = 2 in table2.

Do you mean a union? As in you want

```
User Password Role
Fred Fr3d     1
Fred ???      2
Fred ???      3
```

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with this schema, but it breaks near every rule in the book, and doesn't seem to meet your needs....

Based on your comment, one way you might look at is.

Is

```
Users (UserID, UserName, Password etc) Key UserID
Roles (RoleID, RoleName etc) Key RoleID
UserRoles(UserID,RoleID) Key UserID,RoleID
```

You need to learn a bit about databases particularly normalisation, first three forms should do for most things.

Then

```
Select UserName, Password,RoleName From Users 
inner join UserRoles on Users.UserID = UserRoles.UserID
inner join Roles on UserRoles.RoleID = Roles.RoleId
```

and such like become possible and efficient.

Comment: shud i create only 3 fields in a table like username password and role??

Answer (score 1):

**You should have one table that contains the following columns:**

id (unique, primary), username, password, role (INT, would be assigned 1-3 for principal, staff or corre depending on the user)

*Additionally*

You could have another table called roles if you want set up like this:

id (unique, primary), title (options for title would be principal, staff, or corres)

When the user logs in just do something like

```
if($role == 1){
// redirect to principal page
}
elseif($role == 2){
// redirect to staff page
}
elseif($role == 3){
// redirect to corres page
}
```

I'm not certain but I believe this would work as well. Try this query.

```
(SELECT '1' AS role FROM table1 WHERE username = $username AND password = $password)
UNION ALL
(SELECT '2' AS role FROM table2 WHERE username = $username AND password = $password)
UNION ALL
(SELECT '3' AS role FROM table3 WHERE username = $username AND password = $password)
```

Assuming the user is only located in ONE of those three tables then it should match the username and password and find out which table the user is coming from. Then you can pull out the role by using

```
$role = $row['role'];
```

If the username/password combination is incorrect then $role would be empty or you could fetch the number of rows [using $iscorrectuser = mysql_num_rows($query)] where there is a match and the number of rows would be 0. You could then redirect the user trying to log in with a "Unsuccessful login" error message.

Comment: The BEST option is to use ONE table, I'm not sure why you have three separate tables if all of the information is the same except for the role. If that is the case then just use one table with a column named "role" and all users that are principals have the role = 1, staff = 2 and corres = 3. But there is some other reason to have multiple tables (which sometimes there are) then try the union. I'm not sure all that you are trying to do but it seems like you only need one table, not three.

Comment: shud i use fields username,password role right??in role can i use ENUM type for assigning 1 for corr etc??..iin table shud i use id field also r just userna,pass,role is enough??

Comment: Use the four fields, id (INT, auto increment), username (varchar 50), password (varchar 50), role (INT, 1 or 2 digits).  This way all the users are in one database, they all have their unique id, when they log in the database can check to make sure they have the correct username/password combination and if they do, it will pull what role they have (1, 2, or 3) and redirect them to the correct page. You can add more fields to the table later if you wish like email, phone number, address, etc that way you don't have to try to search 3 tables to try to find one user's information.

Comment: i assigned enum for role field as '1','2','3'..is this correct??? and use this code if($role == 1){
// redirect to principal page
}
elseif($role == 2){
// redirect to staff page
}
elseif($role == 3){
// redirect to corres page
}
$role = $row['role'];

Comment: Yes except you must put $role = $row[$role] ABOVE the if statement, otherwise the variable "role" will not have been declared and will return with a value of 0 and not redirect anywhere. And you have to rename "$row" to whatever is returning the result of your query. For example,

Comment: `$getuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = $username and password = $password", $connection);
$user_exists = mysql_num_rows($getuser);
    if(!$user_exists){
    // redirect to error page or display error message
    }
    else{
    $userinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($getuser);
    $role = $userinfo['role'];
        if($role == 1){
        // redirect to principal page
        }
        elseif($role == 2){
        // redirect to staff page
        }
        elseif($role == 3){
        // redirect to corres page
        }
    } // closes out if the user DOES exist`

Comment: sorry for the formatting, not sure how to do line breaks in comments with limited characters

Comment: <?php
session_start();
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['T_UserName']) && isset($_POST['T_Password']) && !empty($_POST['T_UserName']) && !empty($_POST['T_Password'])){
// username and password sent from form 
$T_UserName=$_POST['T_UserName']; 
$T_Password=$_POST['T_Password'];

// To protect MySQL injection 
$T_UserName = stripslashes($T_UserName);
$T_Password = stripslashes($T_Password);
$T_UserName= mysql_real_escape_string($T_UserName);
$T_Password = mysql_real_escape_string($T_Password);

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$T_UserName' and password='$T_Password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $T_UserName and $T_Password, table row must be 1 row

Comment: if($count==1){
// Register $T_UserName, $T_Password and redirect to file "officeliveadminindex.php"
session_register("T_UserName");
session_register("T_Password"); 
// redirect to error page or display error message
then

if(isset($_POST['emp_role']) 
{

Comment: $userinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
   $emp_role = $userinfo['emp_role'];
    if($emp_role == 1)
    { 
    header("location:corrrespondindex.php");
     } elseif($emp_role == 2 )
  { 
  header("location:principalindex.php");
  } elseif($emp_role == 3)
  {
  header("location:staffindex.php");
   } 
   // closes out if the user DOES exist 



header("location:loginhome.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
}
}
?>...............this is the php code im getting so many error

Comment: i create 1table with id,username,password and role(ENUM,values as'1','2','3'

Comment: yes, next time instead of making 5 comments for all that code, just edit your question and write something like EXTENDED INFO in bold.

Comment: what does the error message say? I only scimmed your code because of the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

session and include functions are given:

```
 session_start();
 include("config.php"); 
 if(isset($_POST['T_UserName']) && isset($_POST['T_Password']) &&         !empty($_POST['T_UserName']) && !empty($_POST['T_Password']))
 {
```

username and password sent from form:

```
 $T_UserName=$_POST['T_UserName'];
 $T_Password=$_POST['T_Password'];
```

To protect MySQL injection:

```
 $T_UserName = stripslashes($T_UserName);
 $T_Password = stripslashes($T_Password);
 $T_UserName= mysql_real_escape_string($T_UserName);
 $T_Password = mysql_real_escape_string($T_Password); 

  $sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$T_UserName' and password='$T_Password'";     $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Mysql_num_row is counting table row:

```
  $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

If result matched $T_UserName and $T_Password, table row must be 1 row :

```
  if($count==1)
        {
```

Register $T_UserName, $T_Password and redirect to file "correspindex.php" :

```
         session_register("T_UserName");
         session_register("T_Password");
```

redirect to error page or display error message then :

```
         if(isset($_POST['emp_role'])
              { 
                $userinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
                $emp_role = $userinfo['emp_role'];
         if($emp_role == 1)
            { 
               header("location:corrrespondindex.php"); 
            } 
              elseif($emp_role == 2 )
               {
               header("location:principalindex.php");
               } 
                elseif($emp_role == 3)
                {
               header("location:staffindex.php");
                } 
           closes out if the user DOES exist:

                header("location:loginhome.php"); 
                 } 
                else
                 { 
                 echo "Wrong Username or Password"; 
                 }
                }
             } 
 php is closed

       this is the php code im getting so many error
       i create 1table with id,username,password and role(ENUM,values as'1','2','3' –
       any else shud i do in the code???
```

Comment: see i just added the full coding.........is this correct..r anything else shud be done