# Select From Radio Button + Enter Username = Open User Profile

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 3 radio buttons, labeled "admin", "manager" and "employee" in registration.php.

When the new user selects a radio button, it should go to the DB.

When the username and password is given on the login page, it should take the user to the appropriate landing page according to the selected radio button:

- admin goes to admin.php
- manager goes to manager.php
- employee goes to employee.php

What fields should be given for the 2 tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much the same question as [Joining tables in MySql with one common field but different values for the common field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955870/joining-tables-in-mysql-with-one-common-field-but-different-values-for-the-commo/8962831#8962831) which you provided an answer on I see (though I didn't read it and don't know if it was correct).

Basically just have ONE table called users with a column for "role" with the values 1-3, 1 being admin, 2 being manager and 3 for employee.

When a user logs in, process the data to check if the password and username are correct which I believe you have already done. If so, check what "role" the user is and redirect them

```
if($role == 1){
// redirect to admin page
}
elseif($role == 2){
// redirect to manager page
}
elseif($role == 3){
// redirect to employee page
}
```

**In response to your comments...**
I apologize as I'm not quite sure what you are asking.. But to retrieve the user's "role" (admin, manager or employee) from the database use

```
$getrole = mysql_query("SELECT role FROM table WHERE username = $username AND password = $password", $conn);
$rowrole = mysql_fetch_assoc($getrole);
$role = $rowrole['role'];
```

Where $conn is your connection to the database, $username is the username entered into the login form and $password is the password entered into the login form. If either the username or password are incorrect then $role will return as a 0 and you can display an error message.

You should have a default role such as employee because I assume there will be more employees than managers or admins, so go into phpMyAdmin and set the column "role" default to As Defined As 1. This means if a user registers and they do not select a role, it will assign them as employee by default. But you can validate this field and force them to select a role. Anyways...After retrieving the users role you find out what page to direct them to.

```
if($role == 0){
// show error message
}
elseif($role == 1){
// redirect to admin page
}
elseif($role == 2){
// redirect to manager page
}
elseif($role == 3){
// redirect to employee page
}
```

Comment: now how to connect the selected radio button value with the logintable ..and when username and password is given how to take to the particular..code please ..i did the code but how to send in comments field

Comment: u can see the same code in the topic joining tables in mysql with one common field but different values for the common field..any additional code to be added please ..help me

Comment: where to insert this code..$getrole = mysql_query("SELECT role FROM table WHERE username = $username AND password = $password", $conn);
$rowrole = mysql_fetch_assoc($getrole);
$role = $rowrole['role'];

Comment: On whatever page processes the login information, right under where you check if the user has the correct password and username, that is where you add the lines about the roles.

You say you already have a query for checking if the username and password are correct, so under that add the query 

`$getrole = mysql_query("SELECT role FROM table WHERE username = $username", $conn);
$rowrole = mysql_fetch_assoc($getrole);
$role = $rowrole['role'];`

Comment: its not going to the corres page when i give username and paassword

Comment: You know how to redirect a page right? Also you may need a different way to connect to your database, I was using the variable $conn as that is how I connect to my database. Sorry this is really basic stuff and this question is basically posted elsewhere which I know you have already viewed. The principal is the same just change their variables with yours. If I had enough reputation to down vote this I would.

Comment: please display ALL of the code you currently have for processing the login form. Add it to the bottom of your question and write **Login Code** in **bold** so I know where to look.

Comment: ok i got the output.............thx to all.............thx  lot guyssssssssssssss

Comment: If this worked for you would you please select it as the answer (checking the check box until it turns green) and upvote it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add column in database "Level" and save one of  "admin", "manager" and "employee" there when registering new user. Then when login you process this with php and redirect to relevant page.